# How do I import protobuf files from one folder in another folder in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, protocol-buffers

I have an existing eclipse project including google protocol buffers. I'm trying to add a new `.proto` in a new folder and then include it from a `.proto` in the original folder.

When I try to build this I get:

> ..\shared\PanicShared.proto: Backslashes, consecutive slashes, ".", or ".." are not allowed in the virtual path

How do I reference another `.proto` in a different folder in eclipse? If I use an absolute file path then the project will not be portable.

If I just import "PanicShared.proto" without the path then the import line itself does not error however inside PanicShared.proto I have:

```
enum PanicLevel {
    NORMAL = 0;
    etc.
}
```

When I try to use that in another message though:

```
import "PanicShared.proto";

message PanicPremium {
  repeated PanicLevel panicPremiumLevels = 11;
}
```

I get an error:

> [protoc]  PanicPremium.proto:9:12: "PanicLevel" is not defined.
>
> [protoc]  [libprotobuf WARNING google/protobuf/descriptor.cc:5411] Warning: >Unused import: "PanicPremium.proto" imports "PanicShared.proto" which is not used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were actually two problems causing this to fail.

The first was that I needed to add the file to the include path and then just use the non-qualified name for the file (i.e. just "PanicShared.proto").

The second was that for some reason I needed to qualify the names of the objects to reference them from that file. i.e. `shared.proto.PanicPremiumLevel` not `PanicPremiumLevel`.

Answer (score 7):

I have normally solved this problem by doing relative includes.

So if this is my structure:

```
  project
   +- dir1
      +- file1.proto
   +- dir2
      +- file2.proto
```

and I want `file1.proto` to include `file2.proto` I do:

```
protoc -I ../dir2 <other args you need> file1.proto
```

And in file1 it will say:

```
import "file2.proto";
```

Here is a worked through example on my machine:

```
$ find `pwd` -type f
/tmp/so/shared/PanicShared.proto
/tmp/so/main/Main.proto

$ cat /tmp/so/shared/PanicShared.proto
enum PanicLevel {
    NORMAL = 0;
}
$ cat /tmp/so/main/Main.proto
import "PanicShared.proto";

message PanicPremium {
  repeated PanicLevel panicPremiumLevels = 11;
}

$ cd /tmp/so/shared

$ protoc -I . PanicShared.proto --cpp_out=.

$ g++ PanicShared.pb.cc -c -o PanicShared.pb.o

$ cd /tmp/so/main

$ protoc -I . -I ../shared Main.proto --cpp_out=.

$ g++ Main.pb.cc -c -o Main.pb.o -I ../shared

$ protoc --version
libprotoc 2.5.0

$ cd /tmp/so/

$ find `pwd` -type f
/tmp/so/shared/PanicShared.pb.cc
/tmp/so/shared/PanicShared.proto
/tmp/so/shared/PanicShared.pb.h
/tmp/so/shared/PanicShared.pb.o
/tmp/so/main/Main.pb.o
/tmp/so/main/Main.pb.h
/tmp/so/main/Main.proto
/tmp/so/main/Main.pb.cc
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, see my edited question - I think I may be one step closer but the import is still not working.

Comment: I have added a full trace of an example based on yours. Perhaps that can help narrow down the differences.

Comment: The only difference I can see is that eclipse is generating the commands for me - the generated commands look identical. I'm heading home now but I'll take another look tomorrow. In the meantime have an upvote in thanks for the help so far :)